# Different standard errors in Julia on regression coefficients

Tags: r, julia, regression

I'm messing around with standard errors trying to make sure I understand them as well as I'd like to but it looks like `lm` and standard matrix algebra have distinct ways of calculating it or maybe my computation is incorrect...

Here's what I ran

```
using DataFrames, GLM, LinearAlgebra, Statistics, LaTeXStrings, PyPlot, Random, Distributions, ProgressBars

stderr = Array{Float64,2}(undef, 20,3)
manstderr = Array{Float64,2}(undef, 20,3)
sigstderr = Array{Float64,2}(undef, 20,3)

_stderr = Array{Float64,2}(undef, 20,2)
_manstderr = Array{Float64,2}(undef, 20,2)
_sigstderr = Array{Float64,2}(undef, 20,2)

σ = 10

for i in ProgressBar(1:Int(20))
    X = rand(Uniform(-100,100), Int(1e6), 2)
    y = 1X[:,1]+3X[:,2] + rand(Normal(0,σ),Int(1e6))
    data = DataFrame(x1=X[:,1],x2=X[:,2],y=y)
    
    # full
    ols = lm(@formula(y ~ x1 + x2), data)
    stderr[i,:] = stderror(ols)
    manstderr[i,:] = diag(var(y - predict(ols)) * inv(ols.mm.m'ols.mm.m))
    sigstderr[i,:] = diag(σ^2 * inv(ols.mm.m'ols.mm.m))
    
    # omit
    ols = lm(@formula(y ~ x1), data)
    _stderr[i,:] = stderror(ols)
    _manstderr[i,:] = diag(var(y - predict(ols)) * inv(ols.mm.m'ols.mm.m))
    _sigstderr[i,:] = diag(σ^2 * inv(ols.mm.m'ols.mm.m))
    
end
scatter(stderr[:,1],stderr[:,2], label="full")
scatter(_stderr[:,1],_stderr[:,2], label="omit")
_ = legend()
```

But then when I measure norm of the difference between the matrices, it's not small enough for me to believe they're doing the same thing.

```
println("full")
println(norm(stderr - manstderr),"\n",
        norm(stderr - sigstderr))
println()
println("omit")
println(norm(_stderr - _manstderr),"\n",
        norm(_stderr - _sigstderr))
```

```
full
0.044288628759881314
0.04428864660024369

omit
0.64138313684955
0.7755064744520012
```

I'd expect the norms should be closer together if they were calculated the same way? I don't think this is due to a rounding error.

I think `manstderr` is how `lm` should be finding the standard errors but I'm surprised they're not closer together. That's why I put in the `sigstderr` computation as well.

---

In case you're curious, this experiment was to see how failing to include relevant yet uncorrelated regressors would effect standard errors.

---

I included in the `R` tag because maybe some `R` people are already familiar with what's happening here. From what I've read in other posts, it seems like there could be rounding error but I don't believe that's true for my case.

Comment: I think you have forgotten to add `sqrt` in your manual calculations.

Comment: Wow. Yeah, you're right. Thank you